# Timeout while trying to deploy to ECS from Travis

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to make an ECS deploy via travis using this script: https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy. Basically, this is the script that I'm using:

```
# login AWS ECR
eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1)

# build the docker image and push to an image repository
npm run docker:staging:build
docker tag jobboard.api-staging:latest $IMAGE_REPO_URL:latest
docker push $IMAGE_REPO_URL:latest

# update an AWS ECS service with the new image
ecs-deploy -c $CLUSTER_NAME -n $SERVICE_NAME -i $IMAGE_REPO_URL:latest -t 3000 --verbose
```

This is the error I'm getting and the verbose info

```
+RUNNING_TASKS=arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxx:task/yyyyyy
+[[ ! -z arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxx:task/yyyyy ]]
++/home/travis/.local/bin/aws --output json ecs --region eu-west-1 describe-tasks --cluster jobboard-api-cluster-staging --tasks arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxx:task/yyyyyy
++grep -e RUNNING
++jq '.tasks[]| if .taskDefinitionArn == "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxx:task-definition/jobboard-api-task-staging:7" then . else empty end|.lastStatus'
+i=2610
+'[' 2610 -lt 3000 ']'
++/home/travis/.local/bin/aws --output json ecs --region eu-west-1 list-tasks --cluster jobboard-api-cluster-staging --service-name jobboard-api-service-staging --desired-status RUNNING
++jq -r '.taskArns[]'
ERROR: New task definition not running within 3000 seconds
```

I don't know if it could be related but I'm getting this error too from python

```
/home/travis/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:369: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  SNIMissingWarning
```

The problem is that the first deploy works correctly, and after the second try it starts to fail. Do I need to make some field dynamic to avoid this?

What do you think the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the same script not on Travis? That is, is there something about the Travis env that is making this happen, or is it just an ECS automation issue?

Comment: Probably this is not an error with your setup but with the application. It seems that AWS will try to deploy the container, and if it errors, it will silently fail. Travis will then try to push the same image again. Only when AWS confirms the push is successful will Travis not Error.